# Best practice to add authorized users to an app engine project via an HTML form

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authorization

I am trying to figure out the best method of adding additional authorized application users through a web form accessed/maintained by a site admin user.

I am thinking that I want to check the `get_current_user()` against a list of authorized users entered by a user with site "admin" privileges (as in not application admin rights to the dashboard etc).

The [examples Ive seen](http://clouddav.googlecode.com/hg-history/19fba540ea20fec4ee301cdf8b9a282332d28f77/src/auth.py) seem to indicate I should use email addresses.  Is that the best practice or is there a way to use the email address to add the entire user property of a Google accout to my datastore as an authorized user?  If so, are there any advantages to doing it?

A follow on question IF the entire user property has advantages is where I might find examples of how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, web apps use email for authentication because you will need to communicate with the user, and email is the best/easiest way to do that, so it's a given that you're going to need an email address for them.  Email addresses are also inherently unique, given that only one person can use an email account (unless they share, which they shouldn't).

I don't believe there is a way to query Google for Google+ records or somesuch.  You could write something to do it, but there's really no advantage to importing all of that, except that you're going to creep them out because you have their picture and such.